# Does leaving the SSRS web page terminate the report?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS, if you have a long running report and you leave the web page (close it, navigate away, etc), does the report terminate on the server or is it still running?  We're on SQL Server 2019.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope.. you can close the page and it will keep running on the server until complete

Comment: That's what I was remembering, but it was many years ago and wasn't sure if that got fixed.  Thanks!